# OpenGl game android not redrawing after the device sleeps

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, sleep

i'm building a simple OpenGl game (after reading the book Beginning android 4 games) , i am using a wake lock to prevent the tablet from going to sleep , but if i do force it into sleeping, on waking up the app just shows a white screen (the clear color )

The game framework is exactly the same as in the book and i'm only trying to build my game step by step the same as Super Jumper (Chapter 9), if anyone can help me out , that would be great

Comment: Any chance of showing some code for people who don't have the book?

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply call View.setKeepScreenOn(boolean) to keep your screen alive and the device active. Other than that... you will proly have to reloard your textures as they are disposed when you lost your opengl context.